# How would I export the two variables from within my component to a different component itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

So im trying to export the two variables locationLat and locationLon for use in another component (that isnt the main App component) and also want to export the Header function component to the App component. What would be the easiest way to do this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 

export let locationLat; 
export let locationLon;

function Header() {

    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    function handleChange(event) {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleClick() {
        const geoCoderURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=" + text + "&limit=5&appid={apikey}"
        function getCoordinates(url) {
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                locationLat = response.data[0].lat;
                locationLon = response.data[0].lon;
                // return locationLat, locationLon;
            });
        } 
        getCoordinates(geoCoderURL);        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Five Day Forecast</h1> 
            <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="name" autoFocus placeholder="Enter location here."/>
            <button type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>Forecast</button> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: the easiest would be to use context - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Actually simplest way would be to use window.variableName, but be aware that this is anti-pattern, change in the variables won't trigger re-rendering etc. So you need to use this carefully.

Comment: Ah ok Ill try using context, im new to react so hadnt heard of it. Don think I could use window.variableName as I want the change in the variable values to trigger a re-render

Comment: I dont think context will work as each component is in its own component file, any other ideas on how to do it